# How to handle subprocesses in linux on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, subprocess, popen

I have been trying to change the system time on an offline Raspberry Pi 4 manually from a Python script that receives the time from a TCP client in the form of a string. As required by my project, the time will be need to be adjusted regularly from an input string. Below is the function I have tried using:

```
import subprocess

def timechange(time):
    cmd = ['exec sudo date +%T -s ' + str(time)]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
    proc.kill()

newtime = "13:00:00"
timechange(newtime)
```

However, I can't seem to consistently get this to change the time successfully using the above function. I have tried using os.open/subprocess.call instead but from other question responses, it seems that using os is not recommended.

All this function needs to do is to change the system time. Does the subprocess automatically exit and close the shell after the command finishes?

Being a beginner, I am not sure if it has to do with the termination of the shell/cmd or if it spawns too many shells. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Why the `exec`?

Comment: @KlausD. I saw in some other response that the exec in front helps to kill the shell process and the command. It was the second highest answer.  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true

Comment: That also explains the `kill()` which is most likely killing your command before it completed. The question you linked is about something very different.

Comment: @KlausD. I see... Sorry i dont really know much about subprocesses. How should I code it such that it does not kill/terminate the process before it completes?

Comment: Why don't you read the python official documentation on the subprocess module?

Comment: You're killing the subprocess prematurely. Try using `proc.communicate()` instead of `proc.kill()`

Comment: @prithajnath wow that worked like a charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: @user202729 Theres alot of information to go through, but I am working on it! just needed some help to point me where to look at. Thanks tho!

Comment: Perhaps either run() or call(). They have a "common usage" section. in the docs,  i think.